# как мне отвечать на вопросы, если у меня мало репутации, заработать ее я получается не могу, ведь нельзя отвечать на вопросы

Tags: поддержка, репутация

Как мне поднять репутацию на этом сервисе, если я не могу зарабатывать репутацию отвечая на вопросы? это замкнутый круг. удалять учетную запись не хочу.

Comment: вот видите, вы даже и вопрос задали не на мете, где ему место. этот факт, хоть и очень косвенно, но всё-таки что-то олицетворяет.

Comment: Почему вы не можете отвечать на вопросы? Кто вам запрещает это делать? @aleksandrbarakin о существовании меты узнают только те, кто туда попал )

Comment: @SwaD хм. а что же это за ссылка в правом углу страницы с картинкой в виде знака вопроса? там какие-то непонятные ссылки, аж четыре штуки, к тому же на одной из них совершенно неясная надпись «обсудить принципы работы и политику сайта». // серьёзно: может, действительно, как-то переформулировать эту надпись?

Comment: Для чего ты хочешь поднять репутацию?

Comment: спасибо большущее, думаю теперь я точно смогу отвечать на вопросы, тег найти нормальный я не смог, извините)

Comment: И, кстати, снова имеем [эту проблему](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292823/339911)

Comment: А зачем вам репутация?

Comment: Я расширил список дубликатов вопросом про блокировку ответов/вопросов. Надеюсь, теперь станет яснее, как действовать дальше.

Comment: Предлагайте правки сообщений. За каждую утверждённую +2 дают.

Answer (score 1):

Поднять репутацию можно, отвечая на вопросы или задавая хорошие вопросы. Я вам поднял авансом в расчёте на ваши будущие успехи :-)

Я видел тут вопросы, которые набрали тысячи голосов, соответственно, авторы получил десятки тысяч баллов!

Comment: Где — тут? На ruSO самый заплюсованный вопрос — 316, на мете — 118. На enSO таких вопросов полно, но мы же не про enSO (голосуют там в разы больше, репу набрать не проблема).

Comment: @Глеб мне так без разницы, ру или ин.