# Дадут мне баллы репутации, если я отвечу на вопрос на мете?

Tags: поддержка, репутация, мета

Если я отвечу на вопрос на мете, мне закинут баллы на обычную учетную запись stackoverflow? Мне кажется, тут их легче заработать, но вдруг тут есть отдельный счетчик баллов с меты?

Comment: Не дадут. Тут вообще баллы особенные. Их как бы нет, но они как быть есть. [Справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: а зачем вам балы ?  а, все вспомнила https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13108/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e //я смотрела ваши ответы, поотвечайте еще, постарайтесь, уверенна и так заработаете. кстати вот согласна https://i.stack.imgur.com/M09cm.png

Comment: ...и кстати кто вам сказал, что тут легче заработать плюсы ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vKiV.png

Comment: ...найдите тот вопрос, что знаете ответ, ответьте по своему опыту на тот вопрос в чем разбираетесь наверняка и точно тестировали. Я лично поставлю плюс, если правильно и красиво информативно и логично оформите. Не ленитесь и не остерегайтесь минусов. Пишите как знаете, и как бы вы хотели услышать(те, кто ставят минусы из вредности, и посылают на минус сами потом сидят в луже- и обсуждаются там тут..., плавали видели. так что не ведитесь на это=по типу оййй, у него больше репы, он меня заминусовал, бла бла...ерунда, ведите свой путь). Напишите, прочитайте, если поняли сами, то уже хорошо.

Comment: Я до сих пор свои старые вопросы /ответы корректирую переодически, через полгода прочитав, не так как в первый день. Мысль самому ясна, а донести граммотно тоже надо уметь.

Comment: Волшебная ссылка (`[meta-help]`) -> [meta-help]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Цитата из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) (выделение моё):

> #### Есть учётная запись на Stack Overflow на русском, есть и на Мете
>
> На Мете Stack Overflow на русском не требуется создавать отдельную учетную запись. Как только вы зарегистрировались на Stack Overflow на русском, у вас автоматически появляется учётная запись на Мете Stack Overflow на русском.
> **Голосования на Мете не влияют на вашу репутация на основном сайте, а репутация на Мете соответствует вашей репутации на Stack Overflow на русском.** Общаясь на Мете, вы можете получить дополнительные знаки. Для участия в обсуждениях на Мете вам необходимо иметь 5 баллов репутации.

**P.S**: Кстати, если в комментарии написать [meta-help], то получится ссылка на нужную статью. Но это только в комментариях.

Пример:

[image: пример комментария с использованием волшебной ссылки]

Comment: про мета хелп не понял

Comment: @MikeNovi [Полный список «волшебных» ссылок раздела справки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2709/186999)

Comment: @MikeNovi это одна из так называемых "волшебных ссылок". Если в комментарии написать `[meta-help]`, то получится ссылка: [meta-help]